# aspxtreelist how to set selection nodes by default (VB)

Tags: vb.net, tree, nodes, treenode, treelist

i'm using visual basic, its my first time using treelist. Any suggestion how to set nodes at aspxtreelist?

i wanted set the nodes at treelist based from sql database.

schema :

**SQL database**

> | id ---- partnerID
>   |
>
> |  1  ---- 2 |
>
> | 2  ---- 3.2
>   |
>
> | 3  ---- 4 |

**Treelist**

the treelist had value 2, 2.1, 2.2, 3, 3.1, 3.2 , 4, 5

> | partnerID --- Command |
>
> |  2 --- + |
>
> | 2.1 --- + |
>
> | 2.2 --- + |
>
> | 3 --- + |
>
> | 3.1 --- |
>
> | 3.2 --- +|
>
> | 4 --- |
>
> | 5 --- |

'+' as nodes

When i load the page, i wanted the treelist had default selection node : 2, 2.1, 2.2, 3, 3.2

i don't know what property which must BE used.

Comment: There's not enough in your question to help you. Show us the declaration of the TreeList in the markup. Show us the code you use to populate it. Are you referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx?

Comment: thanks john.... i had solved my problem.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had solved my problem. here the answer i created :

```
    Dim iterator As TreeListNodeIterator = tree1.CreateNodeIterator()
    Dim node As TreeListNode
    Dim foundRow As DataRow
    Do While Not (_database Is Nothing)
        node = iterator.GetNext()
        If node Is Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        foundRow = _database.Rows.Find(node.Key)
        If Not (foundRow Is Nothing) Then
            node.Selected = True
        End If

    Loop
```

_database is a datatable which i used to collect the value on my database.